# Some doubts about delete and updating table row using Hibernate in Spring application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am quite new in Spring world and I am trying to implement a simple Hibernate DAO but I have some doubts with **delete** and **update operation**

I am using Spring 3.2.1 and Hibernate 4.1.9 and MySQL database.

So in a MySQL database I have a table named **person** having the following structure:

```
mysql> describe person;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| pid       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| firstname | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lastname  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

In my Spring application I have defined the following interface for my DAO that defined the required CRUD operation:

```
package org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring.entity.Person;

public interface PersonDAO {

    public void addPerson(Person p);

    public Person getById(int id);

    public List<Person> getPersonsList();

    public void delete(int id);

    public void update(Person person);

}
```

Then I have implement this interface by the class **PersonDAOImplement** in this way:

```
package org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.andrea.myexample.HibernateOnSpring.entity.Person;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

public class PersonDAOImpl implements PersonDAO {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    // Metodo che inserisce un nuovo record nella tabella person
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void addPerson(Person p) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.save(p);
        session.close();
    }

    /*
     * Metodo che recupera un record, rappresentante una persona, avente uno
     * specifico id dalla tabella.
     * 
     * @param L'id univoco della persona
     */

    public Person getById(int id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        try {
            return (Person) session.get(Person.class, id);
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Metodo che recupera la lista di tutti le persone rappresentanti dalle
     * righe della tabella person
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Person> getPersonsList() {

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        try {

            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Person.class);
            return criteria.list();

        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

    }

    /*
     * Metodo che elimina dalla tabella person la riga avente uno specifico id
     * 
     * @param l'id della persona da eliminare dalla tabella person
     */
    @Transactional
    public void delete(int id) {
        Person personToDelete = getById(id);
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(personToDelete);
        /*Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        try {
            Person personToDelete = getById(id);
            System.out.println("person to delete: " + personToDelete);
            session.delete(personToDelete);


        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        */
    }

    @Transactional
    public void update(Person person){

        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(person);
        /*
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        try {
            System.out.println("UPDATING");
            session.merge(person);

        } finally {
            System.out.println("CLOSE SESSION");
            session.close();
        }
        */
    }

}
```

This example seems to work fine (I have tested it using a main class containing a main method in which I execute the CRUD method to insert row in the table, query for a single row or a list of row, delete a row and update the value in a row)

The only thing that I find strange is that to work correctly in the **delete** and **update** method I have to **get the current session from my sessionFactory object** in this way:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(personToDelete);
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(person);
```

On the contrary when I have to **add or query** a row I have to **open a new session**, in this way:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

Why?

In the previous **PersonDAOImpl** class I have commented the old implementation of **delete** and **update** method in wich I tried to open a new session (as I do without problem in the addPerson and query method) but in this way don't work...work fine only if I get the current session

Why? Is it correct this implementation of DAO object?

Comment: If you are using Spring why not use it's transactional annotations (Repository / Service / Transactional) to do session management (and transaction management) for you?

Comment: I have use Transactional and SuppressWarnings("unchecked") annotation in my class...I have not used Repository because, in this time, I have configured the injection by xml file...

However, unless you have to understand something wrong, I do not think that has to do with my question ...

Comment: It's possible question duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15046622/problems-only-in-deleting-and-upgrading-table-rows-using-hibernate-on-spring-app

Comment: I extended my comment into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start is to read the well-written [Hibernate documentation on transactions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#transactions). It is clearly stated that both `SessionFactory.openSession()` and `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` can be used to obtain session instances, but the do differ in the way the session is obtained.

With `SessionFactory.openSession()` you are forcing Hibernate to open a new session for your needs, which may lead to undesired/unexpected consequences. On the contrary, if `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` is used a `Session` is received from a current *context*, which may mean transaction, request, etc.

To understand it better, consider a following example: you have a service layer which needs to call methods from two DAO objects, like:

```
@Service
public class Service {

    @Autowired
    private FirstDao firstDao;
    @Autowired
    private SecondDao secondDao;

    @Transactional
    public void serviceMethod(int param) {
        FirstEntity firstEntity = firstDao.getFirstEntity(param);
        SecondEntity secondEntity = secondDao.updateSecondEntity(firstEntity);
    }

}
```

You have two options now: to have each of your DAOs implement their methods like `Session session = factory.openSession();` or `Session session = factory.getCurrentSession()`. Your belief is that both method calls (`firstDao.getFirstEntity` and `secondDao.updateSecondEntity`) should use the same session, because, at the very least your `firstEntity` is in detached state after `firstDao` method call finishes (the session should be closed there), and you should reattach it to the new session to make the code work.

But when you call `getCurrentSession` in both DAO methods the same session instance will be returned (as it was opened beforehand by transaction management mechanism). In this case the Hibernate documentation clearly states that

> *You do not need to use the Hibernate Transaction API at all with BMT or CMT, and you get automatic propagation of the "current" Session bound to the transaction.*

and all of your session management happens when you get a session instance in your DAO by calling `Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();` and that's it. Another excerpt from the Hibernate documentation:

> Your application code can access a "current session" to process the request by calling sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(). You will always get a *Session scoped to the current database transaction* (italics mine).

Mind that **Declarative transaction demarcation** by Spring belobgs to the service/business layer, from which you may need to call several DAOs that use the same `Session` object, that is bound to the current transaction context. The session is opened when and transaction is started when the method marked `@Transactional` is called and transaction is committed and the session is closed when the method is executed.

Of course that doesn't imply that session-per-transaction is the only method of implementing transaction management. There are other concepts like *Open session in view*, *Session-per-conversation*, etc. But in each case, your DAOs will get a `Session` object from the current *context* that is in turn managed by Container, or Framework, or by your written code.

Regarding your code, I would suggest to fix the following inconsistencies:

- remove all `@Transactional` annotations from DAO layer implementations
- use only `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` to manipulate with the data
- go for a service layer with transaction demarcation in mind: your methods there should me marked as `@Transactional` and this way Spring will manage sessions and transactions for you (otherwise look for *programmatic transaction demarcation* in Hibernate documentation.

Related material:

- [Transactions and Concurrency of Hibernate official documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#transactions)
- [DAO and Service layer in Spring session management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566618/dao-and-service-layer-in-spring-session-management)
- [Hibernate openSession() vs getCurrentSession()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046662/hibernate-opensession-vs-getcurrentsession)

Answer (score 0):

I will give some hints but you need to dig into source code and documentation.There are lot of concepts here.

Doing some operation on session does not mean that the changes are immediately pushed to db. This depends a lot on the flush mode of the session and operation you are doing. Refer to hibernate documentation on this. Changes are pushed to db when session is flushed. The changes are durable once transaction is committed.

It would have worked if you called `session.flush()` before close, in the commented code but it is unnecessary because of explanation below.

In the above code for update and delete, when call 'getCurrentSession', you either get the existing session or get the new session from `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringJtaSessionContext`(assuming you are using JTA, again dig into code to understand this).

When new session is created Hibernate register synchronization with the transaction. Before complete of the transaction Hibernate will get call back. Here Hibernate will flush the session. In your case the transactions demarcated by spring through the annotations you placed.

I advice you to debug the code from call to 'getCurrentSession' in order t understand what is happening. You will come across these classes/methods depending on your configuration.

```
 org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession()
 org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringJtaSessionContext.buildOrObtainSession()
 org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization
 org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion()
```